# When doesn't jQuery slideDown work but slideUp does?

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, dhtml, slidedown

I am having trouble with slideDown. Instead of neatly sliding down the element starts 'shaking' and than appears straight away without animation. SlideUp on the other hand works flawlessly.

I made a jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4x4PK/1/

The problem occurs when you click the `+` button. `×` button works just fine.

There are some JS pluggins, the `on.('click' ...)` code in question is all the way down at the bottom.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, seems like I found the solution. The problem was I think that the slideDown function needs to know the height of an element before the animation starts (to know the endpoint of the animation).

When I add the element with after() it's too soon to tell it's height.

- the element has to be already inserted otherwise it's height is zero.
- the element must not be already visible

Finally I found this working solution:

```
$(this).closest('.smoking-rate').after( $el );
$el.hide().slideDown()
```

Can somebody confirm, the height is the reason it didn't work?

Comment: Just had the same issue, and its correct that when you try to animate something that is hidden or doesn't have a height set before its done animating it wont know how to animate it, thus not animating it at all!

Answer (score 0):

You should make your call to slideDown upon the completion of your slideUp animation:

```
$el.slideUp(1).slideDown('slow')
```

should be

```
$el.slideUp(1, function(){
  $el.slideDown('slow');
});
```

Comment: I saw the slideUp(1) as a hack somewhere.I tried your code. It sort of works, but the slideUp makes the element blink before the animation and it only works outside the after() function.

Comment: I am quite positive you can chain slideUp and Down no problem anyway.